# Mark Google Sheets comment as done via email?

Tags: google-sheets, gmail

Is it possible to mark a Google Sheet comment as done from that email you're receiving from `<comments-noreply@docs.google.com>` if someone adds a new comment for you?

Comment: this should be doable since April update

Comment: How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have "[Dynamic Email](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/06/dynamic-email-in-gmail-becoming-GA.html)" enabled (gif file from [googleblog.com](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/)).

[image: gmail-dynamic-email]

Have you checked under your Gmail `Settings` the following?

[image]

As you see one must first enable the `Always display external images` option.

The actions you can take with "Dynamic Email" are mentioned at: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9266768

> You can use dynamic email to:
>
> - RSVP to events
> - Fill out questionnaires
> - Browse catalogs
> - Respond to comments
> - Update emails to display the latest content

Comment: Thanks! Sadly doesn't seem to work if you're trying to respond from `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/2/#inbox`, meaning not your main account but one that this email got forwarded to.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe it should be submitted as a [feature request](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762) for Google

Comment: Don't seem to be able to access the community, you? https://www.cloudconnectcommunity.com/ccc/ls/community/g-suite-feature-ideas

Comment: @orschiro You are right. I too get the "_Oops!_" message. I guess the only other way would be (the throw it in the pit way) through: _Inbox_-> _Settings_-> _Help_-> _Send feedback_.